# Python Fabric and password prompts

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I see that there are a few questions regarding fabric and passwords. I know that if I pass -I to fabric then the password I enter is passed to the environmental variable "password." The problem is that I'm prompted for a password when running an ssh command on my remote server to another remote server.

**But**, I don't want to be prompted for a password entry. I am prompted no matter what I try to do. So here's a little snippet of the code:

```
elif "test" in run('hostname -d'):
                print(blue("Gathering Knife info"))
                run("ssh mychefserver knife node show `hostname`.test.dmz")
```

It works just fine when I enter my password. The thing is, I don't want to have to enter my password. Maybe this is because another ssh connection is initiated on the remote host and fabric can't do anything about that.

I could have the script disconnect from the remote host, run the ssh command locally, then reconnect to the remote host to finish the script... but that seems silly. Suggestions?

Getpass info:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 11 2012, 08:34:23) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from getpass import getpass
>>> getpass('test: ')
test: 
'This is a test'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from getpass import getpass

x = Popen('ssh root@host', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)

print x.stdout.readline()
_pass = getpass('Enter your superduper password:')
x.stdin.write(_pass)
print x.stdout.readline()
```

Once connected, you can still input things as if you were on the other machine via `x.stdin.write(...)` so yea, that should work?

DEBUG (just start a cmd promt, navigate to your python directory and write Python):

```
C:\Users>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from getpass import getpass
>>> getpass('test: ')
test:
'This is a test'
>>>
```

Comment: Or whichever input useage you want to use.

Comment: x.stdin.write(getpass('Enter your superduper password:'))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: My guess is that you did `import getpass` in that case, do `getpass.getpass('Enter ... password:')` ( **take note of [from getpass import getpass]** )

Comment: I did the import just like you have it. Confused about the getpass.getpass. I got this:
 x.stdin.write(getpass.getpass('Enter your superduper password:'))
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getpass'

Comment: Do my "debug" edit and see what happens... somethings not right with your Python version or code.. what version are you running?

Comment: Edited my initial question to reflect the debug.

Comment: @mistermister added a edit to my initial code. separated the two lines so `getpass()` inputs into `_pass`

Comment: I think there was something funky in my script. What I did was use your method by itself and it worked. When I entered into my script it didnt work. Thanks for your help and persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it. In short: If you set [`fabric.api.env.password`](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.8/usage/env.html#password), fabric will use it to connect to the servers listed in [`env.hosts`](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.8/usage/env.html#hosts):

```
from getpass import getpass
from fabric.api import env

# Setting env.hosts
env.hosts = ['someuser@someserver.com']

def deploy():
    """A deployment script"""
    # Setting env.password with `getpass`
    # See here for more: http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.8/usage/env.html#password
    env.password = getpass('Enter the password for %s: ' % env.hosts[0])
    # The rest of the script follows...
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to enter your password, you can set up a keypair for authentication. You use  ssh-keygen to generate a public and private key, put the public key onto the remote machine and use the private key as authentication mechanism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-keygen).

Comment: Thanks but that wouldnt be an option for this scenario as the script must be executable by anyone who can login to the initial server. And I don't want to push keys out to every server.

Comment: The initial server being the one fabric is running on? And everyone uses her own account accessing `mychefserver`?

Comment: Yes to both of your questions.

Comment: Users created via chef or a centralized solution like LDAP? If you create them on each machine, pushing a public key is simple, and with ssh-agent-forwarding you can set up a userfriendly solution.

Comment: The issue isn't with chef server or keys. Assume that chef, ldap, etc do not/can not manage users. I know how to setup user management but it is out of my control.